# Android: File listing of web server

Tags: android, web-services, http

I am trying to retrieve file listing from my (apache) http server via an android phone. Searched the web and forum without success. I was however able to do this in standard java using:

```
package at.klp.serverlist;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ivy.util.url.ApacheURLLister;

public class ServerFileListJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url1;
        List serverDir;

        try {           
            url1 = new URL("http://...url to server...");           
            ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();         
            serverDir = lister1.listAll(url1);
            System.out.println(serverDir);         
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Is a similar class available in Android, or can file listing somehow be done using org.apache.http*?
I do not really want to use a WebView, or separate the html code using HttpGet and HttpResponse.

Thanks a lot for helping, any ideas?

**Solved thanks to your answers. I imported ivy-2.0.0-rc1.jar into my project, did not know that this works! This video demonstrates how to import .jar`s into an Android project: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0&noredirect=1
thanks!**

Comment: Have you tried just getting the apache .JAR file that contains this method and using it as an external library? Or do you want something more native to android?

Answer (score 1):

`ApacheURLLister` is a pretty simple class with no special dependencies. You should have no problems copying it and use it directly in your code: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/util/url/ApacheURLLister.java

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio you can add Ivy on the `build.gradle` file

> compile group: 'org.apache.ivy', name: 'ivy', version: '2.3.0'