# Android: How to get list of files that are located in Apache Server? and populate ListView with files

Tags: android, listview

I need to implement a code in an app, which should see the available files on the web server. Display them in the listview with check boxes and finally when user clicks on download button it downloads the files in SDCARD.

I have following things working. 
- Downloading from Web Server and saving in SDCARD (but filenames are hardcoded in URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this solution

> [Android: File listing of web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639024/android-file-listing-of-web-server)

Then iterate over the list and cast it to a string

If what you mean is getting the file name from the URL string you can use

> String.replaceAll();

To replace all the unnecessary part of the string by using regular expression