# Android:get list of files in a url

Tags: android, url

I have searched a lot but cant anything good for android..I hope some one can help me.I want to get a list of files on this url and add them to a string an pupulate in a list view..So my problem is that I cant get list of files from url..here is my url..
[files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganjoor/files/gdb/)

I searched and find this..But It is for java not for android..Is there any way to convert It?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://howto.unixdev.net").get();
        for (Element file : doc.select("td.right td a")) {
            System.out.println(file.attr("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

I also find that server must have directory list ability..Right?How I find server has this ability?
I found this one but It is need to convert :( I am working on it :D
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639024/android-file-listing-of-web-server)

I tested this method but I get error..Can you help me find my mistake?

```
  URL url1;
            List serverDir;

            try {
                  url1 = new URL("http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganjoor/files/gdb/");    
                InputStreamReader urls=new InputStreamReader(url1.openStream(), "UTF-8");
                Log.i("url_string", urls.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

here is log cat

```
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.tosca.persianpoem/co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.hashCode(HttpConnection.java:343)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:298)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:67)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database.onCreate(Download_database.java:45)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-11 08:20:22.772: E/AndroidRuntime(13416):    ... 11 more
```

I cheked the permitions and added this two permitions but still I am getting error..Where is my mistake?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Now I tried this new code and I get error again..Can some one helps me abut this new error?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_database);
    if(isOnline()){


        String contents=getContents("http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganjoor/files/gdb/");
        Log.i("download", contents);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "you are not connected to internet..Please check your connections", 1).show();
    }
}




          public static String getContents(String url) {
                String contents ="";

          try {
                URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();

                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                contents = convertStreamToString(in);
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                //Log.v("MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // Log.e(e.getMessage(), e);
           }

          return contents;
        }
          private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     
                                      InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   } finally {
                        try {
                                is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                return sb.toString();
          }
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here Is error

```
   04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.tosca.persianpoem/co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1108)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database.getContents(Download_database.java:62)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at co.tosca.persianpoem.Download_database.onCreate(Download_database.java:45)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-11 22:13:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

it seams you use it on android. Make sure you got the permission to use internet access!
add this in your manifest:

Ok, what you get here is the "NetworkOnMainThreadException" this is thrown when you try to connect to a Networt in your main Thread.
Why is it thrown?: A Networkconnection may take a long time to get an answer (think of a big file you want to download on a slow internet connection). If you start this download in your main activity - the activity is blocked until the download finished. That means, the user couldnt touch or use anything. Therefor this is forbidden in Android.

You have to do your URL connection in another thread!
I recommand the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html impementation. With the asynctask you can make your results visible in the GUI.

Comment: I'm writing on my mobilephone and it looks like it doesn't work correct... search for android permission.INTERNET

Comment: I have already added this permition :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> Is there any new permitions needed

Comment: yea ... as i said before permission.internet: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: You should do it in background in an AsyncTask