# List-view is not showing server data

Tags: android, android-listview

I have following code to get data from server to list-view.

```
public class ServerFileList extends Activity {

    URL urlAudio;
    ListView mListView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.serverfilelist);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAudio);
        new getAudiofromServer().execute();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    class getAudiofromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ServerFileList.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading audio file to server. Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Inside first try");
                urlAudio = new URL("server-name/folder/folder");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside first catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
            try {
                System.out.println("Inside second try");
                myList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside second catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("ABCD===" + myList);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically what i am trying is listing all audio files from server to list-view, so i got code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639024/android-file-listing-of-web-server) and i have bit modified as per my requirement. But still list-view is empty, it is not showing any data.

I have also imported **ivy-2.0.0-rc1.jar** inside my project..

So what i am doing wrong. How can i list all file of server's particular folder inside list-view. Is this correct or do i need to use some other approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following code

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

to `onPostExecute` of `getAudiofromServer`. If you do this on `onCreate` its possible that `getAudiofromServer` may not have completed execution and hence `myList` may be populated. So the `ListView` will not show any items in it.

If you do it in `onPostExecute` you will have got the list of audio files stored on your server in `myList` and so they will be seen in the `ListView`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but if i move this part inside onPostexecute i get error saying The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(ServerFileList.getAudiofromServer, int, List<String>) is undefined

Comment: You have to use `ServerFileList.this` instead of `this` while initializing `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Okay, that error is solved but still data is not showing in list-view. And it showing exception that `W/System.err(12989): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "i-qualtech.com": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: Either you have not given `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` or you are not connected to the Internet

Answer (score 1):

Your `myList` is not populated until `doInbackground` does its computation.

Move this

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( ServerFileList.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

to `onPostExecute`. Make sure `myList` is populated.